# Error converting a date to ISO 8601 in PHP and remove milliseconds

Tags: php, date-formatting, iso8601

Am working on a date input in PHP whereby I am converting to ISO 8601 which is working fine. It is working fine but I need to remove the last characters which are in milliseconds

PHP code to convert to ISO 8601

```
//Getting the timezone
date_default_timezone_set('Africa/Nairobi');

//CONVERTING TO ISO 8601
$newDate = date('c', strtotime('+24 hours'));
dd($newDate);

//Output after dd
2018-10-25T14:34:44+03:00
```

I need to remove `+03:00` so that the output will be `2018-10-25T14:34:44`

Comment: If you don't want the timezone (those aren't milliseconds), then don't use a date format that contains a timezone. Use [formatting characters](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) to get the correct format to being with, rather than manipulating a different one.

Comment: so i guess you dont really want ISQ8601, ie what you want is not what you ask. AND +03:00 is NOT milliseconds, it is offset from 'Z' .  Read **[this about ISO8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)**

Comment: @John Conde ,, It is not a duplicate,, I need to remove the last characters which is a different question from the other one..

Comment: @YvesLeBorg Okay,, how do I remove it,, I am using that date format to hit an API  which requires a strict format

Comment: @Patweb Yes it is. You just want to change the format of a date and that question explains how to do that. Basically, don't use the `c` formatter.

Comment: why dont you post the spec of that so-called 'strict' API date format ?  you might get more appropriate guidance.  Seems to me this is an **[XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)**.

Comment: @JohnConde Okay,, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about substring?

```
substr(date('c',strtotime('+24 hours')),0,-6)
```

Or, just format as required:

```
date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s',strtotime('+24 hours'))
```